# SignalR Troubleshooting keeping the connection after 25 seconds, and then reconnecting again. NET 7 -> IIS Release

Tags: c#, iis, connection, signalr, release

Right know I have WebAPI only for SignalR, running one hub.
Has JWT authentication by middleware.
The error only occurs when I'm in Release, with Debug mode work 100%.

Images:

SignalR Configuration

[image: SignalR Configuration]

Program configurations

[image: Program configurations]

IIS Advanced settings

[image: IIS Advanced settings]

IIS Pool

[image: IIS Pool]

Client configurations

[image: Client configurations]

Client terminal logs

[image: Client terminal logs]

Pool .NET CLR is the last options is selected.

Client is javascript with more recent packages.

My gool is to be possible to maintaining the connection stable like de debug mode.

Comment: You're not showing any error...

Comment: Every 25 seconds the socket reconnect, and I don't know why.
I'm receveing close message from the server "Information: Close message received from server."
[IIS Configuration - Release](https://imgur.com/a/cjCuCES)

Comment: Did you deploy under IIS also the Debug version or just test it in your local environment?

Comment: I publish Production enviroment, and Release. NET 7
[IIS Publish image](https://imgur.com/a/uU09xGZ)

Comment: Make sure websockets is enabled on your production server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket

Comment: @BernardoGeneroso I'm trying to understand if your working test, the one built in Debug environment, is running in your Visual Studio, or if it is published in IIS.
My guess is that it runs in VS and the problem when you publish is caused by the network (how www.test1.com is resolved?)

Comment: About the error: Close message received from server. Maybe you could create another hub and configure, then call the hub method with a new connection.

Comment: If I remove the configuration of the hub like KeepAlive work fine, but when I add some configuration related to time, the server started OK, but the socket continue reconnecting after 20 or 25 seconds.
I'm publishing in the folder on my pc, I'm using the production environment.

Comment: Why did you increase the keep alive interval.